# Sorting list items up and down not with drag and drop

Tags: jquery, sorting

I want a user to be able to reorder a list on a click event. Here is my code:

```js
$(function() {

  $('#reOrder li').each(function, (index) {

    $(this).attr('id', index);

  });

  $("#reOrder").delegate("li", "click", function() {

    var $indexItem = $(this).index('#reOrder li');

    var $thisTxt = $(this).text();

    var $prevTxt = $(this).prev('li').text();

    $($thisTxt).replaceWith($prevTxt);

    //alert($thisTxt);

    //alert($prevTxt);

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="reOrder">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

So in this example I would like to move the clicked li item and its contents to the position above in the DOM. I suppose strictly speaking it is being moved down in the index of li items.

This is going to be extended later to include buttons that move li items up and down and a submit button that saves the order/state of the list items.

I have found a lot of info on drag and drop (which is not required) but not much on this sort of functionality.

Comment: "which is not required" - do you mean "not required" or "forbidden"? Drag and drop is very intuitive and also works on touchable devices (I hope - I haven't tried).

Comment: Sorry i meant drag and drop functionality is not a requirement here.  I think it would be ideal and add value but the client wants it to function with clickable links that move items up and down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something you might want to check out is the [jQuery UI sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#default)

If you simply want to move items around by clicking etc. have a look at the following methods:

[detach](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) function

[DOM insertion](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-outside/) functions

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $("#reOrder li").click(function() {
        var index = $("#reOrder li").index(this);
        if (index != 0) {
           // li item is not sitting in the first position
           $("#reOrder li:eq(" + (index - 1) + ")").before(this);
        }
    });
});
```

Detach will allow you to remove the clicked element from the DOM and will have a copy available, you can then reinsert in the desired position using one of the DOM insertion functions.

Comment: That's great.  Have updated it now but would like to unbind the click event on the first li to stop them being removed when i click the first item.

Comment: Hi Ryan, have a look at the example function (above), it checks the item at index 0 to make sure it doesn't try calling before() on that item.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  var $ul = $('ul');
  $ul.css({ position: 'relative', height: $ul.height(), width: $ul.width() });

  $ul.find('>*').each(function(i, e) {
    var $e = $(e);
    $e.data($e.position());
  }).each(function(i, e) {
    var $e = $(e);
    $e.css({ position: 'absolute', top: $e.data('top'), left: $e.data('left') });
  }).click(function(e) {
    var $e = $(e.target);
    var $be = $e.prev();
    if (!$be.length) return;
    $be.before($e).stop().animate($e.position());
    $e.stop().animate($be.position());
  });
});
```

http://jsbin.com/eduhaf/4/edit